# unable to hide .php extension. It worked only if i typed manually in url, How to fix it with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

My problem is that when I type the URL without `.php` extension (like as `https://example.com/register`) it worked, but when I click `register` link it redirect to `https://example.com/register.php`. I am trying to edit `.htaccess` file so that by default when I click register link URL should be without `.php` extension.

**My go daddy `.htaccess` file code is**

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: When you "click `register` link" what URL is being requested? If this is the same URL that you type manually then you really should be getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for contribution, and being ashamed myself not to reply your valuable efforts because my boss was asign me a different project.

## working code is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Additionally also remove .php extention from
`<a href="example.php">Example</a>` all anchor tag of the page.
you can check here https://doxdocs.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Use another if not work

```
RewriteEngine On
# remove the index file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index
RewriteRule ^(.*)index$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]  

# remove the .php extension 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# redirect from .php to less php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /([^/]+/)*[^.#?\ ]+\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^.]+)\.php http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi, Anand thanks for help, but its work only for some links but not all and unfortunately one link redirected to http://example.com/folder/register even I changed http://example.com/folder/ to my root directory. that is https://doxdocs.com

Comment: last code is more close to solve the problem but it couldn't work for the pages after loging (for private pages) rather it prevents login.

Answer (score 0):

apply this to your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

it works for all(.php or no .php)

Comment: sorry @Dev it couldn't even redirect to any page.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Options +MultiViews
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
> ```

You've enabled `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) and you are also trying to append the file extension using mod_rewrite. You should do one or the other, not both. They both do essentially the same thing. `MultiViews` is probably "Winning", or worse, creating a conflict.

Your existing code is essentially the same as:

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```